# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue, file not found on Xcode

Tags: xcode, afnetworking, preprocessor, cocoapods, lexical

I have been trying to fix some errors appearing on a code I am currently using. I did all the actions at the ReadMe files,I followed all the instructions given at git, and I still get errors at almost every header (i.e. Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group
config.hpp:19:10: 'boost/config.hpp' file not found)
After some tries, I think that my Xcode project doesn't read the libraries, as it should. I started fixing the problem manually, by setting the exact path of every header, but there is no point to do that, since I am going to use this project in a different computer too, where the repository won't be the same.
After that, I installed AFNetworking 3.0 and CocoaPods, since I read that it would help, but I didn't managed to solve the errors.

I am using
-OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5
-Xcode version 7.0

Comment: OK so where, relative to the project in the filesystem, is `boost/config.hpp`?

Comment: It's in the libs file (libs/include/utils extension)

Comment: What do you mean by "extension"?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it right or I don't get the question. The exact path of the .hpp file is: openFrameworks-master/libs/boost/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp

Comment: No, that would be `boost/filesystem/config.hpp`, not `boost/config.hpp`.